# Multiple rule replace within single column postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to select a column and do a multiple replacement i.e

```
Col1
a
b
c
d
```

select col1 and replace a = 1, b=2 and c=3

```
Col1
1
2
3
d
```

I am aware of update and replace but only for a single rule at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CASE:

```
select
    case when col1 = 'a' then '1'
         when col1 = 'b' then '2'
         when col1 = 'c' then '3'
         else col1
    end
from table;
```